# php undefined after migrating working website

Tags: apache

I copied / rsync all of my website files from one server to the other and nothing has changed minus the linux level but i am getting

PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function n() in /srv/www/htdocs/includes/sidenav-products.php on line 3

Not sure whats missing

```
<div class="sidenav_container">
<ul class="sidenav">
<li><a href="./products_hardware.php"<?=n('products_hardware.php')?>>
<span>Hardware</span></a></li>
<li><a href="./products_data.php"<?=n('products_data.php')?>>Data 
Power</a></li>
<li><a href="./products_xblades_pblades.php"<?
=n('products_xblades_pblades.php')?>>IBM zBX xBlades<br />IBM zBX 
pBlades</a></li>
<li><a href="./products_idaa.php"<?=n('products_idaa.php')?>>IDAA</a>
</li>
    <li><a href="./products_pure_appliances.php"<?
 =n('products_pure_appliances.php')?>>Pure Appliances</a></li>
<li><a href="./products_storage.php"<?=n('products_storage.php')?
>>Storage</a></li>
    <li><a href="./products_systemz.php"<?=n('products_systemz.php')?
>>System Z</a></li>
<br />
    <li><a href="./products_software.php"<?=n('products_software.php')?>>
 <span>Software</span></a></li>
<li><a href="./products_app_dev.php"<?=n('products_app_dev.php')?
>>Application Development</a></li>
<li><a href="./products_bus_analytics.php"<?
=n('products_bus_analytics.php')?>>Business Analytics</a></li>
<li><a href="./products_db_systems.php"<?=n('products_db_systems.php')?
>>Database Systems</a></li>
<li><a href="./products_enterprise_cm.php"<?
=n('products_enterprise_cm.php')?>>Enterprise Content Management</a></li>
    <li><a href="./products_ibm_collab.php"<?
=n('products_ibm_collab.php')?>>IBM Collaboration Solutions</a></li>
<li><a href="./products_info_management.php"<?
=n('products_info_management.php')?>>Information Management</a></li>
    <li><a href="./products_network.php"<?=n('products_network.php')?
>>Network</a></li>
    <li><a href="./products_rational.php"<?=n('products_rational.php')?
>>Rational</a></li>
<li><a href="./products_tivoli.php"<?=n('products_tivoli.php')?
>>Tivoli</a></li>
<li><a href="./products_trans_systems.php"<?
=n('products_trans_systems.php')?>>Transaction Systems</a></li>
<li><a href="./products_websphere.php"<?=n('products_websphere.php')?
>>Websphere</a></li>
    <!--<li><a href="./products_os.php"<?=n('products_os.php')?
>>Operating Systems</a></li> -->
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Clearly you messed up something and you'll have to figure out what. Since you've given no source, this is an exercise you'll need to conduct yourself. We don't have access to your application.

Comment: It's self explanatory. You are calling a function n() which the PHP is not able to locate. You should check if you missed including a file containing the function definition.